# Creating trigger using mysql_setup

Tags: magento-1.9, database, mysql-triggers

I have created custom module and through which i want to created trigger. below is installer code.

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->run("
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER `wishlist_item_delete_after` AFTER DELETE ON `wishlist_item` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE vUser varchar(50);
SELECT USER() INTO vUser;
INSERT INTO `wishlist_itemtacking_log` (`wishlist_item_id`,`wishlist_id`,`product_id`,`store_id`,`added_at`,`description`,`qty`,`deleted_by`,`deleted_at`) VALUES
(OLD.wishlist_item_id,OLD.wishlist_id,OLD.product_id,OLD.store_id,OLD.added_at,OLD.description,OLD.qty,vUser,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
END
|
delimiter;
");
$installer->endSetup();
```

but when i try to reload page to run the installer script it gives me following error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'delimiter |
>   CREATE TRIGGER `wishlist_item_delete_after` AFTER DELETE ON `wishli'
>   at line 1

Please help